# Weird output in printf()

Tags: c, printf

When I run the following code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){

     printf("2/10=%lf 2./10=%lf\n", 2/10, 2./10);
     printf("2/10=%lf\n",2/10);
     printf("2/10=%d\n",2/10);
     printf("2./10=%lf\n",2./10);
     return 0;
    }
```

I expected it to return

```
    2/10=0.000000 2./10=0.200000
    2/10=0.000000
    2/10=0
    2./10=0.200000
```

and instead I get

```
    2/10=0.200000 2./10=0.000000
    2/10=0.200000
    2/10=0
    2./10=0.200000
```

after thinking a bit I can understand that in the first line the `2/10` could get interpreted as a float division instead of an integer one because I have put the `%lf` specifier in the `printf()` (is that really what happens?) but what I cannot explain is why the following `2./10`  prints `0.000000` instead of `0.200000` as it does in the 4th line.

Anyone can explain it to me?

EDIT:

If I change the code slightly I get

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){
      printf("2/10=%lf\n",2/10);
      printf("2/10=%lf 2./10=%lf\n", 2/10, 2./10);
      printf("2/10=%d\n",2/10);
      printf("2./10=%lf\n",2./10);
      return 0;
    }

    2/10=0.000000
    2/10=0.200000 2./10=0.000000
    2/10=0
    2./10=0.200000
```

which seems to support the idea that the `0.2` in the second `printf()` statement actually corresponds to the calculation of `2./10` and the `0.0` in the same `printf()` statement to some undefined behaviour...

Comment: `(2/10)` will always be integer division. You are causing UB (undefined behavior) by passing an integer where a double is expected.

Comment: UB = Undefined Behavior

Comment: So because of the UB caused by the argument `2/10` (which I guess by coincidence gets interpreted correctly) the second argument (`2./10`) is also affected and its result is displayed incorrectly?

Comment: @gunbl4d3 Yes, undefined behavior can have all sorts of strange consequences (and the first argument is not really interpreted correctly: try with `30/10`, which is not likely to display `3`)

Comment: @PascalCuoq Changing everything to `30/10` and `30./10` actually produces 3 everywhere except in the second argument of the first `printf()` statement where it produces zero again. I guess it will have something to do with my compiler (gcc 4.4.5) that accidentally got it right.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 I didn't say to change both! Anyway, I explained why one floating-point argument got printed correctly when there was one floating-point format in another comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2/10` (integer division) is producing `0` which is an `int` type. printing a data with wrong conversion specificationr invokes undefined behavior.

#### C11: 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>282)</sup> If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

Comment: There's no automatic promotion when calling a varargs function.

Comment: @Barmar; I don't know about that.

Comment: Since the function doesn't have declared argument types, how would the compiler know what to promote it to?

Comment: The extraneous arguments of a variadic function are promoted according to “default argument promotion”, where an `int` remains `int`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq; Serching C11 draft :)

Comment: The thing is that in my output `2/10` is actually producing `0.2` and `2./10` is producing `0.0` when in the same `printf()` statement. Also `2/10` is producing `0.2` when alone in a `printf()` statement (with `%lf` as specifier.

Comment: 6.5.2.3:7 in C99 for the mention that default argument promotions apply to variadic arguments.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 In some compilation platforms, the first floating-point argument is passed in a floating-point register and the first integer argument in an integer register. On that particular platform, the first floating-point argument is matched to the first floating-point format because of how the calling convention works. This is still undefined behavior and not something wise to rely on.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Gotta be what you just said. It seems that the 0.2 that I get on both the first and second `printf()` statements actually correspond to the `2./10` and not the `2/10` and the `0.0` that I get on the first `printf()` statement might correspond to a second uninitialized floating-point register or some other undefined behaviour... see the edit at my question.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: `The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument
promotions are performed on trailing arguments.`: What does it mean here by: *stop after the last declared parameter* ?

Comment: @Barmar There _are_ promotions when calling a varargs function, maybe not the ones OP wants.  C11 §6.5.2.2 6 "If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. ..."

Comment: @haccks It means that with `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`, you can expect the first argument to printf to be converted by taking into account the prototype, and that any argument that comes after the first one is promoted according to default argument promotions.